# How can we apply this simple eigenvector expression 'repeatedly'?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $A,B$ be linear operators on a complex vector space $V$ and suppose
$$ABu = (\alpha + 2)Bu$$
where $u \in V$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\alpha$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. We can interpret this as either $Bu = 0$ or $Bu$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\alpha+2$. I'm reading a proof which proves this equation above about the operators $A,B$ as a lemma and then claims that 'by applying the lemma repeatedly' we get the formula
$$AB^ku = (\alpha+2k)B^ku$$

I have tried many things but cannot see how to apply it repeatedly. The lemma seems to a statement about $ABu$, sticking many more $B$'s seems like it would *prevent* us from using it.

The context: $\pi$ is a representation of the Lie algebra $sl(2,\mathbb{C})$ acting on $V$. Above I was letting $A = \pi(H)$ and $B = \pi(X)$ where
$$H = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix} \quad \quad X = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Calculation shows $[X,H] = HX - XH = 2X$, and because $\pi$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism, we have $\pi([H,X]) = [\pi(H),\pi(X)] = 2\pi(X)$. Playing with this equation is what proves the lemma above. Maybe playing with this repeatedly is what is needed.

Comment: Are you sure about the statement written as $AB^ku=(\alpha+2k)Bu$? Can it be instead $A^kBu=(\alpha+2)^kBu$? Also, how do you know that A is invertiblele

Comment: You're right that we don't know $A$ is invertible. I had a typo, now we have $B^k$ on the right, which I missed while I was working on this. I still can't see how to apply it repeatedly though.

Comment: Is there anything else known about $A$ and $B$ . It seems like that the statement cannot be proven with provided information

Comment: I have added more context and information about $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thank you for your hard work Nevzat!

Here is the simple answer. Interpret the lemma as
$$u \text{ is an eigenvector of } A \text{ eigenvalue } \alpha \Longrightarrow Bu \text{ is an eigenvector of } A \text{ eigenvalue } \alpha + 2$$

But then applying this implication with the eigenvector $Bu$ gives $B^2u$ an eigenvector of $A$, eigenvalue $(\alpha +2) + 2 = \alpha + 4$. This is the repeated application, and gives the formula.

Comment: I do not see where in the question you started with the assumption that $u$ is an eigenvector of $A$ to the eigenvalue $\alpha$. From this answer of yours, it seems like the lemma in the text you're reading had as *conclusion* what you present as an *assumption* in your question, while you forgot to insert the actual lemma's assumption, namely, that $u$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\alpha$.

Comment: You're right that I forgot to add that assumption and that that makes the problem *very* different.... I edited the question to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $ABu=(\alpha+2)Bu$

$[\pi(H),\pi(X)] = 2\pi(X) \Rightarrow AB-BA=2B$

$AB-BA=2B \Rightarrow AB^2-BAB=2B^2$

$AB^2-BAB=2B^2 \Rightarrow AB^2u-BABu=-(\alpha+2)B^2u+AB^2u=2B^2u$

$-(\alpha+2)B^2u+AB^2u=2B^2u \Rightarrow AB^2u=(\alpha+4) B^2u$

$BA-AB=2B \Rightarrow AB^3-BAB^2=2B^3$

$AB^3-BAB^2=2B^3 \Rightarrow AB^3u-BAB^2u=AB^3u-(\alpha+4)B^3u=2B^3u$

$AB^3u-(\alpha+4)B^3u=2B^3u \Rightarrow AB^3=(\alpha+6)B^3u$ if we repeatedly apply the lemma we will get

$AB^ku=(\alpha +2k)B^ku$ let's prove with induction. Assume $AB^ku=(\alpha +2k)B^ku$

$AB-BA=2B \Rightarrow AB^{k+1}-BAB^{k}=2B^{k+1}$

$AB^{k+1}-BAB^{k}=2B^{k+1} \Rightarrow AB^{k+1}u-BAB^{k}u=AB^{k+1}u-(\alpha+2k)B^{k+1}u=2B^{k+1}u$

$AB^{k+1}u-(\alpha+2k)B^{k+1}u=2B^{k+1}u \Rightarrow AB^{k+1}u=(\alpha+2(k+1))B^{k+1}u$